# How would I disable the 5 same fields of specific forms in a formset?

Tags: django-forms

Some of the forms represent parent objects and I want most field disabled in each of these forms, if they're for a 'parent' object.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to give the fields a particular semantic class, and then disable all the ones with that class using [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/). Assuming the forms are all contained in some larger container with an id of `formgroup` and you use `dependent-field` as the class name, you can use something like:

```
// Set the 'disabled' attribute on every dependent field in this group of forms.
$('#formgroup').find('.dependent-field').attr('disabled', true);
```